# Need regex to take only the first two sentences even if other instances occur

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I need help with a regex that finds the first two words at the start then takes only the first two sentences after, despite how many instances occur in the text.

```
text = "The Smithsonian museum is home to a variety of different art displays.  According various reports art appreciation is on the rise.  Blah blah blah blah.  The Smithsonian museum blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah."
```

My code looks something like this:

```
(re.findall(r"""((The Smithsonian|The Metropolitan)[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.)""", text))
```

However, this is returning multiple instances instead of just the first two sentences, and oftentimes it returns junk like "The Smithsonian, " at the end.  Can you please help?  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps use an anchor? `^(The Smithsonian|The Metropolitan)[^.]*\.[^.]*\.`

Comment: Do you need to take into account words like "Mr." or "Mrs."?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> `^(The Smithsonian|The Metropolitan).+?(?>\.).+?(?>\.)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not python dev, but the problem seems that you are using `findall`, so as far as I know you can use `finditer` (and search the first iteration) or `search` to find just once match object.

However, if you want to use `findall`, then you can add the `^` anchor to your regex:

```
^((The Smithsonian|The Metropolitan)[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.)
```

**[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB0sV4/1)**

Answer (score 0):

With this `regex`, you don't have to hard code any beginning phrase for the sentences. It will match **exactly 2** occurrences of a sentence followed by the spaces before the next sentence.

```
^((?:\w+(?:\s|\.))+\s+){2}
```

Here is the testing link for it: https://regex101.com/r/mJ4oR7/2

This is assuming there are no special characters within the `string`.

Comment: This looks like something that would be useful however, I need to only take the sentences with those qualifiers in it.  How would I implement this same code with the beginning two qualifiers?  I tried doing it myself but having a bit of trouble  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude "The Smithsonian" etc. from the result, use `(?:)` in the second group:

```
((?:The Smithsonian|The Metropolitan)[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.)
```

Now your group 0 should only return the sentences.

```
>>> x = "The Smithsonian museum is home to a variety of different art displays.  According various reports art appreciation is on the rise.  Blah blah blah blah.  The Smithsonian museum blah blah blah.  Blah blah blah blah."
>>> y = re.findall(r"""((?:The Smithsonian|The Metropolitan)[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.)""", text)
>>> y[0]
'The Smithsonian museum is home to a variety of different art displays.  According various reports art appreciation is on the rise.'
```

See also [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group).